# List Users / User roles and their default timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a table in a postgres DB that consists of "timestamptz" and "timestamp" columns. Recently I have found some discrepancies in the data. Investigating it lead to the fact that multiple users have been used to insert the data. I'm assuming based on user role/user, the default timezone varies which caused the discrepancies.
e.g. I believe some query has been executed as follows, thus changing the timezone for users / roles

```
ALTER ROLE my_db_user IN DATABASE my_database
SET "TimeZone" TO 'UTC';
```

Now I would like to list user roles and their default timezones as well as a list of users and their default timezone, Instead of login as every single user and finding the timezone as

```
show timezone();
```

How can I achieve this? This would aid me to ensure the data integrity even if in the future some user's default timezone has changed, I can use a reference table to identify the timezones.

Any path to documentation or query would be quite helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [pg_db_role_setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-db-role-setting.html). Though if the values are actually being stored in a `timestamptz` field I'm not seeing what the issue is as they will be stored as UTC.

Comment: Hi, apologies, Missed the part where I also have timestamp. Fixed it over an edit

Answer (score 0):

This would be a query:

```
SELECT r.rolname,
       coalesce(  /* if no per-user setting, use global one */
          split_part(s.pair, '=', 2),  /* the value after the = */
          current_setting('TimeZone', TRUE)  /* global time zone setting */
       )
FROM pg_roles AS r  /* list of roles */
   LEFT JOIN pg_db_role_setting AS rs  /* get the per-role settings if they exist */
      ON r.oid = rs.setrole
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL unnest(rs.setconfig) AS s(pair)  /* unpack the array */
      ON s.pair ^@ 'TimeZone'  /* but only get the settings that start with "TimeZone" */;
```